# Clear Dalvik-heap manually

Tags: android, heap-memory

Is it possible to clear the dalvik heap manually, or to initiate the garbage collector shortly before the max heap size is reached?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: If you need to garbage-collect manually, use _System.gc()_.

Comment: @MattiaFranchetto I don't think that's quite manual GC, just an indication to Dalvik that now would be a good time to focus on GC. But I believe there's not much more that can be done.

Comment: You're right, but that's the only thing you can do.